# My program only returns the root of the tree rather than printing the whole tree

Tags: java, tree

```
public Queue<Integer> store_inorder(node n){
    Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<>();
    if(n.left!=null)store_inorder(n.left);
    q.add(n.data);
    if(n.right!=null)store_inorder(n.right);
    return q;
}
```

I've been trying to store Inorder expression of a tree into a queue, But my program doesn't work. What's the problem with my program?

Comment: Make following line a global variable.
Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<>();

Comment: Please indent your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when you use `Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<>();`, you reinstantiate your variable q. So everytime you call your method, you get a new empty `LinkedList`.

To fix this, you just have to store `q` outside the method, like so:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();

public Queue<Integer> store_inorder(node n){
      if(n.left!=null)
          store_inorder(n.left);
      q.add(n.data);
      if(n.right!=null)
          store_inorder(n.right);
      return q;
}
```

To learn more in detail how this behaves, I suggest you research a bit about *the scope of the variables in java*.

Comment: Please recheck the code. @Nathan Your code is same as OP's

Comment: @efex09 Indeed, I inadvertendly reverted my code when logging x( Thanks for pointing i tout!

Comment: method scope is different from outer. So if your `q` param not a global , you can't use in `store_inorder` method. Can you check ?

Comment: @drowny You don't need to have the queue as a global variable. Your method `store_inorder` is public, and the method does have access to the member `q` located in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Queue<Integer> store_inorder(node n){
    //Create a queue where inorder traversal will be stored.
    Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<>();
    // call the function to store inorder traversal of tree rooted at 'n' into 'q'.
    store(n, q);
    return q;
}
public void store(node n, Queue<Integer> q){
    if(n.left!=null) store(n.left);
    q.add(n.data);
    if(n.right!=null) store(n.right);
}
```

Comment: Please give an information about your post. Dont post only code please.

Comment: Also, you are still recreating the Queue everytime you call `store_inorder(node n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<>();` in all recursive method call. So you can solve this problem with parameter passing to method. So like ;

**in your method call**

```
..
// if you already have a queue list to add new node, please send to store_inorder method instead of creating new instance
Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<>();
store_inorder(node n,q);
//now in q , new node was set. 
//do it something on changed q.
..
```

And your method should change like ;

```
public void store_inorder(node n, Queue<Integer> q) {
    if (n.left != null) store_inorder(n.left);
    q.add(n.data);
    if (n.right != null) store_inorder(n.right);
}
```